# Client (desktop app) ...Server (web app) - Intranet solution - should proxy situation be considered?

Tags: proxy, intranet

There's a client server application.
Client - .NET 2.0 based desktop application.
Server - ASP .NET 2.0 based web application.

The client communicates with the server using normal HTTP requests, since the server is essentially a website hosted on a web server.

This solution is primarily for intranets - i.e. the web application is hosted on one of the internal servers in the network.

**In this architecture, does the client need to be built to manage proxy settings?**

Since the web server is inside the LAN, under this situation, is access to an internal web server also configured through proxies? Or are proxies strictly for all Internet calls from machines in the intranet?

Comment: ?? Might this be more appropriate for stackoverflow ???

Comment: Maybe, but I think having the sysadmin take on it probably isn't a bad thing. I know I've had to suffer thru application software that just wasn't written to handle proxies when I needed it to. Sometimes developers need to hear from those of us who actual administer the use of their products... *smile*

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, any application that uses HTTP ought to be capable of using an HTTP proxy. Nicest would be if your application supported proxy autoconfiguration. You can't ever predict every environment the application is going to end up getting used in, and, as a sysadmin, I value flexibility with respect to adapting to network environments in application software.

Since you're using .NET, depending on how you're doing your HTTP you may be able to get this all "for free" from the underlying native code.

Comment: I suspect there is a configuration is .NET where the application (creating the HTTP requests) uses the same connection configuration as Internet Explorer.  Google Chrome does this ... Firefox doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Proxies on the LAN are only useful if you're going to be doing some kind of filtering or accounting. I don't see them being useful in your case as long the app usage stays on the LAN.